# coroutines handling in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made 4 animations in 4 `GameObjects (Rockgroup_x)` and I want to start one animation at random after 2 sec, then after 2 sec the next random animation etc.. All the animations are tested and work. First I set all these `GameObjects` inactive so you won't see them at first, and when I need them I make them active in the function `Rocksplants()` and wait for 2 sec and then it starts all over again. But the `coroutine` doesn't work correct. I only see the game looping the animation of the RockGroup_2 GameObject. What am I doing wrong and how can I make this `coroutine` work?
Can somebody help me please.

Error message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   RocksPlants+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/ChosenAssets/Scripts/RocksPlants.cs:25)

*(line 25: GameObject Rockgroup_02; )*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RocksPlants : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator Rocksplants(){

        GameObject Rockgroup_01;
        GameObject Rockgroup_02;
        GameObject Rockgroup_03;
        GameObject Rockgroup_04;

        Rockgroup_01 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_1");
        Rockgroup_02 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_2");
        Rockgroup_03 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_3");
        Rockgroup_04 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_4");

        Rockgroup_01.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_02.SetActive(false); //line 25
        Rockgroup_03.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_04.SetActive(false);

        int rndrockgroupright = Random.Range (1, 5);

        if (rndrockgroupright == 1) {
            Rockgroup_01.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 2) {
            Rockgroup_02.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 3) {
            Rockgroup_03.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 4) {  
            Rockgroup_04.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        }   
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        StartCoroutine (Rocksplants());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there even a object named "RockGroup_2" in the hierarchy?

Comment: I know you referring to the  NullReferenceException but there is a RockGroup_2 in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the assignment of gameobjects shouldn't be done inside the coroutine method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RocksPlants : MonoBehaviour {

        GameObject Rockgroup_01;
        GameObject Rockgroup_02;
        GameObject Rockgroup_03;
        GameObject Rockgroup_04;

    IEnumerator Rocksplants(){





        Rockgroup_01.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_02.SetActive(false); //line 25
        Rockgroup_03.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_04.SetActive(false);

        int rndrockgroupright = Random.Range (1, 5);

        if (rndrockgroupright == 1) {
            Rockgroup_01.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 2) {
            Rockgroup_02.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 3) {
            Rockgroup_03.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 4) {  
            Rockgroup_04.SetActive (true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        }   
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Rockgroup_01 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_1");
        Rockgroup_02 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_2");
        Rockgroup_03 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_3");
        Rockgroup_04 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_4");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        StartCoroutine (Rocksplants());
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your advice, and now I got no more error messages. However now the animations switch every frame instead of every 2 sec, and they don't start but only show the first picture ?.

Comment: your are still starting the Coroutine every frame. Refer to the other answers

Answer (score 2):

I read that starting a coroutine in an update function will cause problems because it will start every frame the coroutine that has to wait 2 sec, so I used the MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating function to reach my goal, and it worked :->  !.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RocksPlants : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject Rockgroup_01;
    GameObject Rockgroup_02;
    GameObject Rockgroup_03;
    GameObject Rockgroup_04;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Rockgroup_01 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_1");
        Rockgroup_02 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_2");
        Rockgroup_03 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_3");
        Rockgroup_04 = GameObject.Find("RockGroup_4");

        InvokeRepeating ("Rocksplants", 0.5f, 2.0f);

    }

    void Rocksplants() {

        Rockgroup_01.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_02.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_03.SetActive(false);
        Rockgroup_04.SetActive(false);


        int rndrockgroupright = Random.Range (1, 5);

        if        (rndrockgroupright == 1) {
            Rockgroup_01.SetActive (true);

        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 2) {
            Rockgroup_02.SetActive (true);

        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 3) {
            Rockgroup_03.SetActive (true);

        } else if (rndrockgroupright == 4) {  
            Rockgroup_04.SetActive (true);

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Coroutine is being called in the Update function each frame. You may wanna cache your Coroutine Rocksplant and make your update check if thag routine is null or not so when its null you re-call the routine again. This is how yoi cache it.

E.g

```
private Coroutine MyRocksplantRoutine = null;
```

Make it global btw.
Now on your Update function you do this

```
Void Update()
{
    If(MyRocksplantRoutine == null)
    {
        MyRocksplantRoutine = StartCoroutine(Rocksplant());
    }
}
```

This way you can keep it in the update function without making duplicate call on it. After that you null the variable MyRocksplantRoutine at the end of your Rocksplant Coroutine like like so.

```
void IEnumerator Rocksplant()
{
    //your code
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    MyRocksplantRoutine = null;
}
```